# How to use CSS Pseudo class with Semantic UI buttons?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I want the buttons from Semantic UI to change color when I hover over them. I know how to do that with regular CSS, but I want to incorporate it specifically with the buttons from Semantic UI.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have markup for button like

```
<button class="ui button">Follow</button>
```

Then use

```
.button:hover {
background-color: #efefef; /* color of your choice*/
color: #222;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using !important and your custom style sheet file should be included after semantic library file